# How to display Database Notifications using Laravel?

Tags: laravel

I want to display all of the notifications that belong to a single User.
CandidateNotificationsController.php file:

```
public function index()
    {

        $notifications = Auth::user()->notifications();

        return response()->json($notifications, 200);
    }
```

But when I `dd(Auth::user());` All I get is the User, there's no Notifications table relationship there.

I've successfully been able to create notifications, by adding the `use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;` and `use Notifiable;` to my Users model, but I'm having trouble fetching and displaying them.

I'm confused, do I need to create a Notifications.php model and then create a relationship between Notifications and Users? I thought this was done by default with Laravel?

Comment: But it has nothing to do with vue

Comment: Okay, I modified my post and removed Vue.

Answer (score 1):

You can access the notifications collection by using the [`User::$notifications` property](http://$notifications%20=%20Auth::user()-%3Enotifications();):

```
$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications;
```

By using the `User::notifications()` method you'll get an instance of the [Eloquent query builder](https://laravel.com/api/7.x/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html) back which you can use to further constrain the results of the relationship before actually fetching them from the database:

```
$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications()->limit(5); // Will limit the SQL query to 5 results
```

Comment: For some reason I had to create a Notification class and create a relationship between that and the User. Only Now does this work ```$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications;```. I've never had to do that before...

Comment: Yikes, that's pretty odd behaviour. Ususally the notification model [ships directly](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/7.x/src/Illuminate/Notifications/DatabaseNotification.php) with the framework itself.

Comment: I just deleted Notification.php model and now it's working still and I constantly clear my cache when developing, so weird.

Answer (score 0):

You need to call get at the end.

```
$notifications = Auth::user()->notifications()->get();
```